# Disable tabbar in special buffers

Tags: buffers, customize, customization, tabbar

I have [Tabbar](https://emacswiki.org/emacs/TabBarMode) installed and when I am using some function like `describe-key` in emacs the resulting `*help*` buffer has a tab bar at the top. This is a waste of space and is distracting. How can I disable the tab bar in popup buffers or just special buffers in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(add-hook 'help-mode-hook 'tabbar-local-mode)
```

**tabbar-local-mode**:

```
Toggle local display of the tab bar.
With prefix argument ARG, turn on if positive, otherwise off.
Returns non-nil if the new state is enabled.
When turned on, if a local header line is shown, it is hidden to show
the tab bar.  The tab bar is locally hidden otherwise.  When turned
off, if a local header line is hidden or the tab bar is locally
hidden, it is shown again.  Signal an error if Tabbar mode is off.
```

Comment: Awesome! This is just what I was looking for! Do you know if there would be some way to disable it in all special buffers? I could not find anything like a `new-buffer-hook`.

Comment: Actually I found it. `special-mode-hook`. Thanks again!

Comment: It only works the first time.